# How to to extract response by XPath Extractor in JMeter?

Tags: xpath, jmeter, web-testing, beanshell

I got the response like the following:

```
<response>
  <status code='200' server_time='xxx' />
  <tests>
    <test id='1' name='a!' status='Started' />
    <test id='2' name='bb!' status='New' />
    <test id='3' name='ccc!' status='New' />
    <test id='4' name='dddd!' status='New' />
  </tests>
</response>
```

I have already added a Xpath extractor into the sampler:

```
Reference name: mytest
XPath Query: //test[@id='1']
```

But the return variable (mytest) is wrong.

```
OUT.println(mytest) --> void
```

I'm a newbie with JMeter. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: This JMeter Xpath Extractor Guide should help you to get familiar with XPath Expressions: https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/10/jmeter-xpath-extractor/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have already added a Xpath extractor
>   into the sampler:
>
> Reference name: mytest XPath Query:
>
> ```
> //test[@id='1']
> ```
>
> But the return variable (mytest) is
>   wrong.
>
> ```
> OUT.println(mytest) --> void
> ```

Obviously the `println()` function prints the string value of the `test` element, and in the provided XML document `test` elements do not have any content and their string value is the empty string.

**You want**:

```
/*/*/test[@id=1]/@name
```

and

```
/*/*/test[@id=1]/@status
```

The former  selects all `name` attributes of all `test` grandchildren of the top element of the document, that have an `id` attribute with value `1`.

The latter selects all `status` attributes of all `test` grandchildren of the top element of the document, that have an `id` attribute with value `1`.

Comment: @Dimitre: excuse me, but it still not work. I have tried @id="1" as well, but nothing happens.

Comment: @Hoàng-Long: This means that either you are evaluating the XPath expressions against some other XML document with different structure/names or that you are using a non-compliant XPath engine. I would recommend to use the XPath Visualizer (http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html) and refine your XPath expression until it selects exactly what you want.

Comment: @Dimitre: thanks, I have figured it out. The problem is that I use tidy mode, and somehow it stops XPath Extractor from getting the value. Many thanks for the expression, though :)

Answer (score 2):

It could be because you have no text content. Try setting "`Return entire XPath fragment instead of text content?`"